# Codename One Theme corrupted - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: codenameone

I've added a MutliImage using CodeName One Designer. I've added the image as a background of a component. Started getting an exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.readMultiImage(Resources.java:1096)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.readMultiImage(Resources.java:1069)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.createImage(Resources.java:1051)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.createImage(Resources.java:961)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:306)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:269)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:189)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:740)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:702)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:666)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initNamedTheme(UIManager.java:1583)
    at gymrush.pro.RushPro.init(RushPro.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:117)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.io.IOException: 0
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:755)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:702)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:666)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initNamedTheme(UIManager.java:1583)
    at gymrush.pro.RushPro.init(RushPro.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:117)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

I've removed the image and the style, nothing helps. Even created a new theme and removed the old one, same problem. Also tried to use:

```
public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "rush-pro");
}
```

No luck here. I would rebuild the theme from scratch and start again, but how can I do this without starting a new project?

Maybe there is better way to solve the problem?

Comment: It looks like the theme was corrupted. You get this exception before the code to access the image occurs. When you say "removed the image" what do you mean by that? Is the res file 0 size? Do you have the XML hierarchy under the res directory?

Comment: I've just clicked on delete icon on the image from CodeName One Designer. I had to move on and rebuilt the project from, I didn't check what I had under res directory. If I'll get into the problem again, that would be the first thing I'll check.

Comment: The res directory will include XML and image files if XML team mode is enabled under the file menu. We recommend backing up the res file and ideally committing it to versioning to avoid corruption.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog This is a good advice, but it looks like if the file is corrupted, there is no way to rebuild it without starting a new project. Also, I was able to reproduce the situation when I've corrupted the theme. I was adding SVG file and got NPE. I think that corrupted everything.

Comment: SVG support isn't used much and doesn't actually use the SVG's since they aren't supported on modern devices (ironically they were only supported on J2ME devices). If you are interested in SVG support this approach is probably better: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/flamingo-svg-transcoder.html